# Как проверить наличие ключа в переменной?

Tags: php

Получаю данные через cURL запрос:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);

...

echo $response;
```

Как проверить в $response наличие цифр **123456**?

**Видимо как-то так?**

```
if (in_array(123456, $response)) {
echo 'что-то';
exit;
}

... дальше пошло продолжение скрипта ...
```

Если да, то как прекратить выполнение дальнейшего скрипта, если 123456 не найден и как выполнить дальнейший скрипт, если 123456 найден?

p.s. **$response является html документом (страница сайта)**.

Спасибо!

Comment: Попробуй die; или exit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$response** у вас строка, по этому нужно проверять или строковыми функциями например [strpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php), или регулярными выражениями например [preg-match](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: Спасибо, сделал с помощью strpos